# Blackberry - MS exchange combination strips in-reply-to & reference header from email

Tags: blackberry, email, exchange-server, email-headers

I am working on system for adding mail replies to some database.

Currently this does not work with "Blackberry + Microsoft exchange" combination.

It works well with "Ipad + Exchange", "Blacberry + gmail", "Desktop +exchange" combination.

I noticed when we send mail from Blackberry on exchange server, it strips out the "in-reply-to" & "reference" headers from email.

My logic relies on these two headers to perform the operation.

Any idea what is going on Blackberry (9700) + MS exchange combination?

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw the same behavior when using a Blackberry to reply to an email message; my reply was sent either without the In-Reply-To header, or with an unexpected value (i.e. something other than the exact Message-ID value of the original).  It seems others have noticed this as well:

http://blog.mindslip.info/2008/01/email-threading-headaches-threadaches.html